# Will cards obtained during the Hearthstone beta be lost after the game goes live?

Tags: hearthstone

After a game leaves beta, [Blizzard typically removes all statuses earned during a game's beta](http://forums.battle.net/thread.html?topicId=24401614785&sid=5000). Is this going to be the same for cards earned during the beta phase of Hearthstone? Will all the work I am putting into collecting cards and leveling heroes be removed when the game goes live?

Comment: Sorry, but this is speculation of the future of the industry.  They have said they won't, but there's no guarantee one way or the other that they won't.

Comment: @fbueckert I did both a question and answer because there are a ton of bad forum posts on the internet. If things change I will modify the answer or someone else can if I'm slow to do so. For now I was trying to help the internet by putting up a canonical answer to a frequently asked question.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is still off-topic; nothing done here plays to our strengths.  All you're doing is repeating what's already been said.  We're not a news service.

Comment: I'm with @ahsteele here, the question and answer are well thought out and informative, with ample references.  Though this isn't a news site, it does fit to have an authoritative answer to a relevant question.

Comment: Since the game deals with real money purchases in beta (unless I'm mistaken), this seems like an extremely important question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On [October 2nd, 2013 Blizzard wiped all progress](http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/blog/11144301/) made during the initial Hearthstone closed beta. In the [announcement post of the then impending wipe, Blizzard](http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/blog/11100276/) made it clear that there would be ***no further card wipes*** and hero leveling progress would carry forward into the release of the game. If you need more evidence read on.

From the aforementioned [Hearthstone Account Wipe Incoming](http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/blog/11100276/) post:

> **Will there be any wipes in the future?**
>
> We don’t anticipate any further wipes. This goes for both the
>   Hearthstone beta and after the game’s official release. Any progress
>   made during the beta after the wipe will be retained through the
>   release of Hearthstone, such as new cards you obtain, levels that you
>   gain and ranks you achieve. Basically, you’ll now be able to keep your
>   stuff.

If that does not alleviate your concerns the [Hearthstone FAQ](http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/faq/) has further information concerning [cards earned during the second phase of the Hearthstone beta](http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/faq/#q7a):

> **Will the cards I earn or purchase in the beta test carry over into the
>   live game? What happens if I purchased beta card packs for real money?**
>
> At this point in the closed beta, all purchases will exist in your
>   game going forward. Also, as a thank you for testing out the in-game
>   store during Hearthstone’s beta phase, everyone who purchased a card
>   pack or entry into The Arena in the beta test will receive a Golden
>   Legendary card, Gelbin Mekkatorque.

Finally, Aratil a "blue" (Blizzard community manager) on the Hearthstone forums had this to say about the [potential for future Hearthstone card wipes](http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/forum/topic/10467316955#18):

> There are currently no plans for another wipe.